# array counting sort segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, counting-sort

Hello i am trying to use counting sort to sort numbers that i read from a file. this is my code:

```
    void CountingSort(int array[], int k, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    int B[100], C[1000];
    for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
    {
        C[i] = 0;
    }

    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        C[array[j]] = C[array[j]] + 1;
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1];
    }

    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        B[C[array[j]]] = array[j];
        C[array[j]] = C[array[j]] - 1;
    }

    printf("The Sorted array is : ");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }
}


void max(int array[],int *k,int n){
    int i;
    printf("n je %d\n",n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > *k) {
            *k = array[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(int brArg,char *arg[])
{

    FILE *ulaz;
    ulaz = fopen(arg[1], "r");

    int array[100];
    int i=0,j,k=0,n,x,z;


    while(fscanf(ulaz, "%d", &array[i])!=EOF)i++;

    fclose(ulaz);
    n=i;

    max(array,&k,n);
    printf("Max je %d\n",k);
    CountingSort(array,k,n);
    return 0;
}
```

i have no errors but when i start my program i get Segmentation fault error. pls help! (dont read this bot is asking me to write some more details but i have none so i just write some random words so i can post my question and hopefully get an answer)

Comment: Does you program crash if you remove the `CountingSort(array,k,n);` in your `main` function?

Comment: Adding onto that I would throw in some debug statements to help you determine where the seg fault is happening.  Once you've done that it will be easier for others to help you

Comment: Build a debug version, and run in a debugger. The debugger will then stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine and (more importantly) walk up the function call stack to your code. There you can examine values of variables. At the very least you should edit your question to indicate where in *your* code the crash happens. You should also provide the input that causes the crash.

Comment: when i remove countingsort it does not crash. it works fine

Comment: i dont rly know how to do the debugging thing.. i am kinda new to programming.. but i will try to do something with some DDD program and try to get some results

Comment: `C[array[j]] = C[array[j]] + 1;`  suppose `array[j]=2000` it will obviously show segfault as you have declared `int c[1000];`

Comment: oh my god it works when i changed array[100] to array[2000]... when i declare array[200] it doesent work,when i declare array[300] it works.. damn i dont understand why

Comment: No you should't do that again.because if array[j]=4000 then it will crash again.

Comment: you have to learn how to debug using the tools of your compiler / platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your implementation of the counting sort is incorrect: it uses arrays as if they were one-based, while in C they are zero-based.

After carefully going through your loops and fixing all situations where you use a `for` loop that goes `1..k`, inclusive, instead of the correct `0..k-1`, the code starts to work fine:

```
int i, j;
int B[100], C[1000];
for (i = 0; i <= k; i++){
     C[i] = 0;
}
for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
     C[array[j]]++;
}
for (i = 1; i <= k; i++){
     C[i] += C[i-1];
}
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  B[--C[array[j]]] = array[j];
}
printf("The Sorted array is : ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   printf("%d ", B[i]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/lQaRT8)

**Note:** I modified some of the operations to use C-style compound assignments and increments/decrements, e.g. `C[array[j]]++` in place of `C[array[j]] = C[array[j]] + 1` etc.

Comment: thank you for you help. but there is funny thingy going on now. it doesent show seg fault its sorts numbers but kinda. in my file my max number is 70. so program now does sort other numbers nicely but insted of putting 70 last it puts some random high number at start. exmpl: number 2 5 1 3 70... sorted 123124 1 2 3 5

Comment: @MarkoB This is because `C[array[j]]` needs to be decremented before the `B[C[array[j]]] = array[j];` assignment. I combined the pre-decrement with the assignment, and fixed the demo.

Comment: now it works perfecty! i cant thank you enough for your help! thank you so so so much!

Comment: @MarkoB You are welcome! If the problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would indicate to other site visitors that you are no longer actively looking for an improved solution, and earn you a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is here

```
int B[100], C[1000]; // C has space for numbers up to 999
...
for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1]; // adding up till C[k] == sum(array)
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    B[C[array[j]]] = array[j]; // B has space up to 99, but C[k] is sum(array)
```

so you're reserving space for `C` for a highest value of 999 but in `B` you're assuming that the sum of all input values is less than 100...

the resolution of your problem is to first probe the input array and get the maximum and the sum of all input values (and minimum if the range may be negative) and allocate space accordingly

edit: you probably meant `j < n` and not `j <= n`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to dasblinkenlight's spot-on answer:

Is your input data guaranteed to be in the range `[0, 999]`? If it isn't, it's obvious that segmentation faults can and will occur. Assume that the maximum value of `array` is 1000. `C` is declared as

```
int C[1000];
```

which means that C's valid indices are `0, 1, 2, ... 999`. But, at some point, you will have the following:

```
C[array[j]] = ... /* whatever */
```

where `array[j] > 999` so you will be attempting an out-of-bounds memory access. The solution is simple: probe `array` for its maximum value and use dynamic memory allocation via `malloc`:

```
/* assuming k is the maximum value */
int * C = malloc((k + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

Note: an alternative to this, which would also nullify the need for an initialization loop to make all elements of `C` equal to `0`, would be to use `calloc`, which dynamically allocates memory set to 0.

```
// allocate C with elements set to 0
int * C = calloc(k + 1, sizeof(int);
```

Another important factor is the range of your running indices: you seem to have forgotten that arrays in C are indexed starting from `0`. To traverse an array of length `K`, you would do:

```
for (i = 0; i < K; ++i)
{ 
    processArray(array[i]); 
}
```

instead of

```
for (i = 1; i <= K; ++i)
{
    processArray(array[i]);
}
```